# Get access-token and authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net, box-api, restsharp

I have to upload files to **box.com** for that i need authorize and get `accesstoken` and refresh token. I am not finding any code in c# asp.net.i want code for authentication using c# and asp.net and code for getting `accesstoken` and refresh token. I tried below code am getting error as page is Expired request again.
Here is the code in c# asp.net.I am trying using `Restsharp`

```
public void GetAccessToken(string code, string ClientId, string ClientSecret)
    {
        RestClient rs = new RestClient();
        string grant_type = "authorization_code";
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        IRestRequest reuest = request;
        string strHeaders = null;
        RestResponse response = default(RestResponse);
        IRestResponse resp = response;
        string strResponse = null;

        try
        {
            rs.BaseUrl = "https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/token";
            request.Resource = "oauth2/token";
            strHeaders = string.Format("grant_type={0}&code={1}&client_id={2}&client_secret={3}", grant_type, code, clientId, Clientsecret);
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", strHeaders);
            resp = rs.Execute(reuest);
            strResponse = resp.Content;

            Label1.Text = strResponse;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:
https://developers.box.com/oauth/
(See "Getting the Access Token")

When exchanging an auth code for a set of access tokens and refresh tokens, you need to make a POST request to the https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/token endpoint.

Try taking what you're adding in the "Authorization" part of your header, and putting it in a URL encoded POST body.

Or even better, try the available .NET SDK which will handle this very part of the OAuth workflow for you:
https://github.com/box/box-windows-sdk-v2

Answer (score 0):

You also need to set the encoding with:

```
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Xml;
```